# Image magically increasing in dimensions when set to an ImageView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

I'm setting an image (jpeg) resource to an ImageView that has dimensions 877x3719. However when I run the app it tells me:

```
W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture (2631x11157, max=4096x4096)
```

Which is exactly triple the original image's dimensions. Does anyone know how or why it's tripling the dimensions without anything in my java code telling it to?
Below is the layout XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView2" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/testlay">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:contentDescription="@string/imageph" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:contentDescription="@string/imageph" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:contentDescription="@string/imageph" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:contentDescription="@string/imageph" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: There is no reference to any drawables in there, how do you set the image on your ImageViews? I'm guessing your drawable is in the `drawable` folder, try putting it into `drawable-nodpi`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ImageView has its size measured in dips (device independent pixel), which can be different for devices with different screen density (like regular and "retina" iPhone).

But when we set image to it, for maximum quality we need to assign value for each *screen* pixel, that's why your image dimensions are "tripled" — for one dip there are three screen pixels.

Comment: I've explicitly rescaled the image when setting it to the imageView using:
imageView1.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.rsz_17_18_21),877,3719,true));

Is this an efficient way to go about this tripling issue or is there a better fix?

Comment: You can put your drawable to `drawable-nodpi` to avoid auto-scaling instead of creating scaled bitmap. In your case you're creating 2631x11157 by upscaling first (it'll be made by Android automatically), then downscale it to 877x3719. It can affect performance and memory usage (and image quality, too)

Comment: `drawable-nodpi` is definitely the correct solution.